# Using Javac in C#?

Tags: c#

Okay, so I've been working on this a while (and I've gone through multiple questions to get this far in the project).

Here's the C# code I'm using:

```
 Process p = new Process();
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 p.StartInfo.FileName = "javac";
 Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath + @"\TempJavaalfgwaepfgawe"));
 p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-d " + Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath + @"\TempJavaalfgwaepfgawe") + " " + files;
 p.Start();

 p.WaitForExit();
 MessageBox.Show(p.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
```

In essence, I am trying to invoke the Java compiler (javac) from a C# application.

Now, when I do this, it wasn't compiling the java code correctly, so I inserted the RedirectStandardError and UseShellExecute as well as the WaitForExit and MessageBox at the end to see the error that was occurring.

Anyways, the error is as follows:

> javac: invalid flag: 2010\Projects\Java
>
> Usage: javac [options] [source files]
>
> use -help for a list of possible options

So, what's wrong with my code?

To me, the error looks like part of the location of one of the file paths.

Comment: Perhaps unquoted paths with spaces in them???

Comment: Add quotes before and after the path you are passing in for the -d option.

Comment: Fixed it. You guys are awesome. I love this website.

Answer (score 2):

I suggested the fix in the comments, but I also wanted to add a formal answer for others with this problem.

When you pass in arguments to a process, strings that have spaces need to be quoted. This tells the argument parser that you really mean one argument. (different arguments are usually divided by white space)